# Azure Synapse Sql - Include Subfolders with _ and . in Extraction

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

SQL that does not pick up all the files in main folder and subfolders. Azure Synapse and Sql on Demand so beware there is a lot of normal sql that does not work yet in it.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://companyland.dfs.core.windows.net/storageboxes/data/*.snappy.parquet',
        FORMAT='PARQUET'
    ) AS [r];
```

In this DATA folder there are folders called MONTH_10 and then in that there is one folder for each day like Day_1 which then contains parquet files for the day. In the DATA Folder , directly under it there is also 5 parquet files . In all the subfolders for this year there are 50 parquet files.

When I execute the above sql in Synapse, it only returns 5 files instead of 55 files as it should be including the subfolders. Looking at the microsoft docs it is because the subfolder names have a _ or . in them.

To pick up the day files separate I need to change query to this :

```
SELECT *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://companyland.dfs.core.windows.net/storageboxes/data/*/*/*/*',
        FORMAT='PARQUET'
    ) AS [r];
```

Also unusually I found that Azure Snyapse does not like union statements in a create view statement, so I was wondering is there a way to change my BULK statement so all 55 files get picked up ?

Comment: When you use * in OPENROWSET path, you can specify finite level of subfolders to be read. Example: https://storage....../container/sales/year=*/month=* will read all folders within sales that start with year= and all folders within starting with month= but it will not read any subfolder beneath month=* folders.

Comment: Thank you for that information. There is also a recursive option in the pipeline for sources so will be interesting finding how that works.

Comment: If below answer is helpful in implementing the requirement, accept it as it can be beneficial for the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are screenshots showing the testing I did and query used. I have kept files with single entry specifying the folder they are in. Example: Month_1 folder -> day_1 folder -> file has month1day1 as data in it.

[image]

Storage Structure:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]